# Automatic scheduling (courses) via SDS (Classic) CSV 2.1 or other means for TEAMS

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I already have a sync set up on SDS (Classic) CSV v2.1 that sets up classes on TEAMS (I retrieve my institution's data via an API). But I would like to also automatically set up the institution's courses (e.g., math from 2pm to 3pm for class 01 etc..). So far, I haven't seen the possibility with SDS to do this or I missed something.. do you know if it's possible to set this up directly automatically via SDS? or by some other means as I can't find this information anywhere at the moment..

Thank you in advance for your answer and your help.